# Implicit Function Theorem

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Show that the equations
$$2e^x + yu - 4v + 3 = 0$$
$$y \cos x - 6x + 2u - w = 0$$
can be solved for functions
$$x = f_1(u,v,w)$$
$$y = f_2(u,v,w)$$ 
in a small ball with centre $(3,2,7)$ such that $f_1(3,2,7)=0$, $f_2(3,2,7)=1$.

Comment: I know I have to use the implicit function theorem and jacobian matrix. but i dont know how to do the steps to get the answer

Comment: It would be good if you wrote where you're stuck, what ideas you have and what you have tried in the post.

Comment: Define f:R^2 x R^2 -> R^2 by f(u,v,w) = (2e^x + yu - 4v + 3, y cos x - 6x + 2u - w).

Comment: (Continue)
f is C^1 (R^2 x R^2) ie, f and its partial derivatives of order <= 1 are continuous (I'm not so sure about this, i just got it from my notes but I couldn't understand the C^1 for)
f1(3,2,7) = 2e^x + yu - 4v + 3
f2(3,2,7) = y cos - 6x + 2u - w

J(f) = det(df1/dx df1/dy
           df2/dx df2/dy)
     = det (2e^x              u
            -y sin x - 6    cos x)
     = 2e^x cos x - [u(-y sin x - 6)]
     = 2e^x cos x + u (y sin x + 6)
     = 2e^x cos x + 3(y sin x +6)

That's my answer but i doubt its correct...

So can you tell me what's the answer now??